# How do I get the environment variable value from Jenkins Plugin implementation?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, implementation

Is there a way to get the environment variable value inside a Jenkins Plugin implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

[Variable substitution in Jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512887/variable-substitution-in-jenkins-plugin)

Comment: Thanks so much @ashish-dhandharia. It solved my problem:

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much [Ashish Dhandharia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1265490/ashish-dhandharia). It solved my problem.

```
final EnvVars env = build.getEnvironment(listener);
String envVarValue = env.get("ENTER_ENV_VAR_HERE");
```